# Web3.js calling ERC721 contract methods

Tags: web3js, erc-721, method

I'm writing a React app that calls to see who the owner of a tokenId is.

I am trying to call the built-in function **ownerOf(uint256 tokenId)** from the ERC721 contract.

Here is my javascript code:

```
const GetOwnerOf = async (tokenId) => {
  console.log(`Getting owner of ${tokenId}`);

  const bc = new web3.eth.Contract(bannerContractABI, bannerContractAddress);
  const r = bc.methods.ownerOf(tokenId);

  console.log(r);
  return r;
}
```

I'm seeing this in my console (Chrome):
[image]

I have confirmed that the contract ABI is correct and the contract address is correct.

How do i retrieve the data? The **ownerOf** function returns an address, how do i view this address?

.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding to the previous answer, use `await` since all the methods are async.

```
const r = await bc.methods.ownerOf(tokenId).call();
console.log(r);
```

Answer (score 1):

You didnt actually call:

https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.11/web3-eth-contract.html#id29

need to do `bc.methods.ownerOf(tokenId).call(blah)`